# Sobrecarga de operadores usando punteros en C++

Tags: c++, operador, sobrecarga

¡Hola! Como parte de un ejercicio con clases en C++, nos piden representar y operar con numeros racionales. El problema viene cuando se pide sobrecargar los operadores {+, -, *, /, =, ==}.
El programa debería ser capaz de ejecutar las siguientes lineas:

```
int main(){
    Racional *r1 = new Racional(2,3); // 2/3
    Racional *r2 = new Racional(3,9); // 3/9
    Racional *resultado = r1 + r2; // resultado = 1/1
    resultado->mostrar();
}
```

Pero al sobrecargar de la manera:

```
Racional* operator + (Racional r){
    // codigo de la funcion...
}
```

da error en la linea

```
Racional *resultado = r1 + r2;
// y debo ponerlo as para que compile:
Racional *resultado = *r1 + *r2;
```

¿como debo hacer para poder ejecutar el primer codigo?

¿no se puede hacer algo del estilo de:

```
Racional* operator + (Racional *rac1, Racional *rac2){
    // codigo de la funcion...
}
```

?

Comment: Para completar la pregunta, ¿ podrías indicar el error exacto que estás obteniendo ?

Answer (score 2):

**No puedes**.

```
Racional *
```

**Es un tipo en si mismo**; no es que sea una instancia de `Reacional`. Su nombre completo es `tipo puntero a Racional`.

¿ El problema ? Pues que los punteros forman parte de los tipos *primitivos* del lenguaje ... y no se les puede añadir operaciones (no de ese tipo, al menos).

En código, lo que tu pretendes es algo como esto:

```
puntero-a-racional puntero-a-Racional::operator+( puntero-a-Racional ) {
  // código
}
```

Y eso está **prohibido**; los tipo-puntero tienen su propio `operator+( )`, que se usa en la aritmética de punteros.

No tienes mas remedio que usar un no-tipo-puntero como primer argumento:

```
Racional *Racional::operator+( const Racional * ) const {
  // Aquí el código
}
...
int main( ) {
  ...
  Racional *resultado = *r1 + r2;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: ¡ Ah carajo ! Cierto, gracias :-)

Comment: Mucho mejor así ;)

Answer (score 1):

> ¿no se puede hacer algo del estilo de:
>
> ```
> Racional* operator + (Racional *rac1, Racional *rac2){
>      // codigo de la funcion...
>  }
> ```
>
> ?

No. Es imposible.

#### Problema: sobrecargas prohibidas.

C++ prohíbe explícitamente la sobrecarga de operadores sobre tipos que no sean objetos. Esto es necesario porque si se pudieran sobrecargar los operadores de tipos fundamentales, podría romperse la aritmética de todo el lenguaje:

```
int operator+(int a, int b) { DestruirElMundo(); return 0; }

int main()
{
    return 2 + 2; // ¡¡DESTRUIMOS EL MUNDO!!
}
```

Dado que los punteros, no son objetos, C++ prohíbe también sobrecargar los operadores que trabajen sobre punteros:

```
struct S{};

S *operator+(S *, S *) { return nullptr; }

int main()
{
    S *a, *b;
    std::cout << a + b;
    return 0;
}
```

El error que muestra el código anterior es:

> ```
> error: 'S* operator+(S*, S*)' debe tener un argumento tipo clase o enumerado
> *operator+(S *, S *) { return nullptr; }
>  ^~~~~~~~
>
> error: los operandos de tipo 'S*' y 'S*' no son válidos para el operador binario 'operator+'
> std::cout << a + b;
>              ~ ^ ~
>              |   |
>              S*  S*
> ```

Y éste es el problema que encuentras en tu código:

```
Racional *r1 = new Racional(2,3); // 2/3
Racional *r2 = new Racional(3,9); // 3/9
Racional *resultado = r1 + r2; // resultado = 1/1
```

Tanto `r1` como `r2` son de tipo puntero (puntero a `Racional`), y ya hemos visto que sobrecargar los operadores de punteros no está permitido en C++.

#### Problema: Tipos de datos.

Cuando creas esta sobrecarga:

```
Racional* Racional::operator + (Racional r){
    // codigo de la funcion...
}
```

Estás indicando que el objeto `Racional` estará a izquierda del operador `+` y a la derecha de dicho operador recibirá una instancia de `Racional`, por lo tanto es normal que esto falle:

```
//                    vv <--- El tipo de r1 es 'Racional *'
Racional *resultado = r1 + r2;
//                         ^^ <--- El tipo de r2 es 'Racional *'
```

Ya que tanto `r1` como `r2` son de tipo puntero (puntero a `Racional`) no de tipo `Racional` y no existe el operador `Racional *operator+(Racional *, Racional *)` porque (como ya hemos visto) C++ prohíbe explícitamente esos operadores.

En cambio es normal que funcione cuando se des-referencia:

```
//                    vvv <--- El tipo de *r1 es 'Racional &'
Racional *resultado = *r1 + *r2;
//                          ^^^ <--- El tipo de *r2 es 'Racional &'
```

Se llama a `Racional *Racional::operator+(Racional)` porque el operando a la izquierda del `+` es `Racional` y a la derecha también lo es.

#### Solución:

Para redactar el operador, usa referencias constantes:

```
Racional operator + (const Racional &rac1, const Racional &rac2){
    // codigo de la funcion...
}
```

Si haces que los parámetros del operador sean referencias constantes, evitarás copiar el parámetro al operar y le darás pistas al compilador para optimizar, se puede usar así:

```
int main() {
    // Con punteros:
    Racional *pr1 = new Racional(2,3); // 2/3
    Racional *pr2 = new Racional(3,9); // 3/9
    Racional resultado1 = *pr1 + *pr2; // resultado = 1/1
    resultado1.mostrar();

    // Con instancias:
    Racional r1(2,3); // 2/3
    Racional r2(3,9); // 3/9
    Racional resultado2 = r1 + r2; // resultado = 1/1
    resultado2.mostrar();

    // Con instancias anónimas:
    Racional resultado3 = Racional{2,3} + Racional{3,9}; // resultado = 1/1
    resultado3.mostrar();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda. Ya logré hacer operaciones entre Racionales.

El problema que tengo ahora es cuando quiero operar entre Racional y int, por ejemplo:
    Racional *r1 = new Racional(1,2);
    Racional *r2 = *r1 + 2;

intente haciendo:
    Racional* operator +(Racional &r1, Racional &r2){
        return r1.suma(&r2); 
    }
    
    Racional* operator +(Racional r1, int i){
        Racional *r2 = new Racional(i);
        Racional *ret = r1.suma(r2);
        delete r2;
        return ret;
    }

Pero me dice 'multiple definition of `operator+(Racional&, Racional&)'